# Flow-Router not working for root url

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I'm having a strange problem where Flow-Router isn't triggering the action for the root url

```
FlowRouter.route '/',
    name: 'home'
    action: ->
        BlazeLayout.render 'appLayout', header: 'header', main: 'home'
```

This delivers a blank page, but when I change the route to something else, like '/dog' and go to that URL, the action triggers and the page is rendered

I'm using Flow-Router 2.10.1